# Smart Button action or method not working

Tags: python, odoo

Good day, I want to get the bank details a client via a smart button in odoo 14. The code below gives me an error when i run it.

```
def action_bank_details_preview(self):
    action = self.env["ir.actions.actions"]._for_xml_id("base.res_partner_bank")
    action['domain'] = [('partner_id','=',self.partner_id.id)]
    action['context'] = {'default_partner_id': self.partner_id.id}
    return action
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml or external ID for the default bank accounts menu action is `base.action_res_partner_bank_account_form`

And try to use the correct model: `ir.actions.act_window`.

Or another way is to use `self.env.ref(<xml_id>).read()[0]`

```py
def action_bank_details_preview(self):
    action_xml_id = 'base.action_res_partner_bank_account_form'
    action = self.env.ref(action_xml_id).read()[0]
    action['domain'] = [('partner_id','=',self.partner_id.id)]
    action['context'] = {'default_partner_id': self.partner_id.id}
    return action
```

Comment: Thank you it is working, but if i want to find this The xml or external ID where should i go next time